# PHP - edit multiple entries

Tags: php, foreach, html-table, edit

Given this form, shown as a table:

```
<form action="multi.php" name="multi[]" method="POST" class="forms">
<table class="table-hovered">
 <tr>
  <th class="text-left highlight">attività svolta</th>
  <th class="text-left highlight">categoria</th>
 </tr>
<?php
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $k => $v)
{
    $q_item = "SELECT * FROM eventi WHERE id = '".$v."'";
    $qu_item = mysql_query($q_item);
        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qu_item))
        {
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $res['descrizione'];?></td>
  <td>
   <select name="categoria">
    <option value="<?php echo $res['categoria'];?>" selected><?php echo $res['categoria'];?>
    <option value="80"> 80
    <option value="40"> 40
    <option value="70"> 70
   </select>
  </td>
    <input type="hidden" name="idd" value="<?php echo $res['id'];?>">
 </tr>
<?php
        }
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="modify" />
</form>
```

I am trying to edit multiple entries, using the code below:

```
<?php
$utente = $_SESSION["username"];
$id = $_POST["idd"];
$categoria = $_POST["categoria"];
if (!$id or !$categoria){
echo "Error";
}
else
 if ($categoria!=='80' && $categoria!=='40' && $categoria!=='70'){
 echo "Error";
}
else{
$sql="UPDATE eventi SET categoria='$categoria' WHERE id='$id'";
$update=mysql_query($sql);
echo "Entry modified correctly";
}
?>
```

As you see, this code changes just one item. I have tried making it recursive. Maybe using a "foreach" is the way to go.

Any hints are appreciated. And sorry for using an old version of PHP (I haven't switched to version 7 yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to create any `hidden` input element in the first place, you just have to change the `name` attribute of `<select>` element in the following way,

```
name="categoria[<?php echo $res['id'] ?>]"
```

So your code should be like this,

```
<form action="multi.php" name="multi[]" method="POST" class="forms">
<table class="table-hovered">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-left highlight">attività svolta</th>
        <th class="text-left highlight">categoria</th>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $k => $v){
    $q_item = "SELECT * FROM eventi WHERE id = '".$v."'";
    $qu_item = mysql_query($q_item);
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qu_item)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['descrizione'];?></td>
        <td>
            <select name="categoria[<?php echo $res['id'] ?>]">
                <option value="<?php echo $res['categoria'];?>" selected><?php echo $res['categoria'];?>
                <option value="80"> 80
                <option value="40"> 40
                <option value="70"> 70
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="modify" />
</form>
```

And this is how you can process your form to perform `UPDATE` operation,

```
foreach($_POST['categoria'] as $id => $categoria){
    $sql="UPDATE eventi SET categoria='". $categoria . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
    // execute your query
}
```

---

**Note:** If you want to see the complete array structure, do `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 2):

As you have **same** names for both `input` and `select` the last value of each of them overwrites previous values. For passing multiple values in inputs with same names - use `[]` notation:

```
<select name="categoria[]">
    <option value="<?php echo $res['categoria'];?>" selected><?php echo $res['categoria'];?>
    <option value="80"> 80
    <option value="40"> 40
    <option value="70"> 70
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="idd[]" value="<?php echo $res['id'];?>">
```

After that - check your `$_POST` values with `print_r` - you will see that 
`$_POST[categoria]` and `$_POST[idd]` are **arrays** and you can iterate over them with `for` or `foreach`.

**Btw**, inserting an `<input>` right after `</td>` produces **invalid** html.

Comment: I forgot the [] notation. Would you use `for` or `foreach`?

Comment: I might try this then: `foreach ($_POST['idd'] as $k => $v)
{
$sql="UPDATE eventi SET categoria='$categoria' WHERE id='$id'";
$update=mysql_query($sql);
}`

Comment: Not `$categoria` but `$_POST['categoria'][$k]`. Same to `$id`.

Comment: I will test it and post the results.